# Dynamically creating a div and appending a list of div's inside the created div using java script

Tags: javascript, html, css

Through java script, I have to create a div. Inside that div i have to append a list of div's (which are loading dynamically), So that i am going to apply a border for that parent (created) div.
For ex:. If i got dynamically loaded 10 div's, i have to create a parent div for every 3 div's, so that i can apply a border for that parent div of 3 div's.

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="div_item">
        item 1
    </div>
    <div class="div_item">
        item 2
    </div>
    <div class="div_item">
        item 3
    </div>
    <div class="div_item">
        item 4
    </div>
    <div class="div_item">
        item 5
    </div>
    <div class="div_item">
        item 6
    </div>
    <div class="div_item">
        item 7
    </div>
    <div class="div_item">
        item 8
    </div>
</div>
```

For these list of items, i have to create a parent div for every 3 div's. Can anyone help me to find a solution.?

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Hi Evan, Thanks for notifying me. I have edited the question. Could you able to recognize the problem or do you need more attention to the problem.

Comment: So, given a certain number of divs, you need to wrap them up in groups of 3?

Comment: How are loaded the divs?

Comment: Yes Evan. Giorgio, the div's are loading dynamically. I can't have control over it. i just need to wrap every 3 div's inside a newly created div.

Comment: @AbdurRahman: I've uploaded a couple of snippets. Let me know if they are working or if some changes are needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a container for elements, you can append elements to it with the jQuery `append()` function. Make a loop over elements and wrap them in groups of 3.

```
var nodes = 21; // total number of nodes

for (var i=0; i<nodes; i++)
{
    if(i%3==0) {
        $('#container').append('<div class="parent"></div>');
    }

    $('.parent').last().append('<div class="child">child '+ i +'</div>');
}
```

[**Fiddle1**](http://jsfiddle.net/qsf36x72/)

Of course, this snippet can be extended to cases where data is loaded i.e. from an AjaX call to a back-end script (please note the use of `nodes.length` on the second loop, which allows you to loop without knowing the size of results).

```
// Create array (can be made with data load from backend)
var total = 21;
var nodes = new Array();

for (var i=0; i<total; i++)
{
    var desc = "child" + i;
    var node = {id:i, description:desc};
    nodes.push(node);
}

// Output results
for (i=0; i<nodes.length; i++)
{
    if(i%3==0) {
        $('#container').append('<div class="parent"></div>');
    }

    $('.parent').last().append('<div class="child">'+ nodes[i].description +'</div>');
}
```

[**Fiddle2**](http://jsfiddle.net/qsf36x72/2/)